# How to add a user to an embedded tomcat in a spring boot application?

Tags: java, spring, maven, tomcat, spring-boot

I am trying to create a spring boot application, everything runs fine except when I have to insert the username and password when I access localhost:8080. I don't know how to add a new tomcat user to the embedded tomcat from my app.

This is my pom xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.mastercrafters</groupId>
    <artifactId>mastercrafters</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>mastercrafters</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

</project>
```

And here is the structure of my project where tomcat is visible:

[image: embedded tomcat folder]

[image: Login from localhost]

How can I disable the login from application.properties if possible or what solution is for this problem ? Many thanks in advance !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have Spring Security as a dependency.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

If Spring security is on the classpath and no security config is made in your application, Spring will configure basic authentication. This is a fail safe. You can find the generated username and password in your console.

You have two options:

- If you don't want a login system, remove the spring security dependency
- If you do want security, you need to configure spring security so that spring knows what authentication mechanism is used (basic, form, oauth, etc.) and how to authenticate users.

Answer (score 1):

You can refer below link to configure Embedded tomcat through application.properties file only. You can also use external tomcat where you can give tomcat-users.xml as before.

```
server.tomcat.basedir= # Tomcat base directory. If not specified a temporary directory will be used.
```

http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-create-a-deployable-war-file

Comment: I tried many ways to make it work with tomcat-users.xml, no luck. @Vijendra Could you please specify how do one need to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to read up more on how the default Spring Security Filter Chain works - you don't need Tomcat users (like is you wanted to access the Tomcat Manager app) - you need to allow Anonymous Auth, or some other form of Autnetication otherwise it will deny any request to the service.

Answer (score 0):

In **spring boot 2.x**, you can use the default security settings (default user and password printed to the console), or can implement your own **UserDetailsService**, as described in spring-boot documentation [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#jc-authentication-inmemory) and [here](https://spring.io/blog/2017/09/15/security-changes-in-spring-boot-2-0-m4#consistent-customization);

This is a detailed example on how to dynamically set your own user/password:  [stackoverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50325960/6792588)