# Spring Boot 2 security basic authentication

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

Why following basic security configurations do not apply inMemoryAuthentication() clause?

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .csrf().disable()
            .httpBasic()
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().authenticated();
        super.configure(http);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
            .withUser("username").password("password");
        super.configure(auth);
    }

}
```

After the application initialization, there is still only default `user` generated by Spring itself, there is no such user like `username`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do not call super method from `void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)`. It sets `disableLocalConfigureAuthenticationBldr` flag to `true` that leads to your `AuthenticationManagerBuilder` being ignored. Finally your `void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)` method should look like this:

```
@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
            .withUser("username").password("password").roles("USER");
}
```

Comment: It's a little bizarre because in most case method is supposed to call `super`. But thank you for your notice, seems work for me

Answer (score 5):

In spring boot 2.x, you will have to implement your own **UserDetailsService**, as described [here](https://spring.io/blog/2017/09/15/security-changes-in-spring-boot-2-0-m4#consistent-customization) and [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#jc-authentication-inmemory)

Example:

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private static final Logger log = LogManager.getLogger();

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // Note: 
        // Use this to enable the tomcat basic authentication (tomcat popup rather than spring login page)
        // Note that the CSRf token is disabled for all requests
        log.info("Disabling CSRF, enabling basic authentication...");
        http
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/**").authenticated() // These urls are allowed by any authenticated user
        .and()
            .httpBasic();
        http.csrf().disable();
    }

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        // Get the user credentials from the console (or any other source): 
        String username = ...
        String password = ...

        // Set the inMemoryAuthentication object with the given credentials:
        InMemoryUserDetailsManager manager = new InMemoryUserDetailsManager();
        String encodedPassword = passwordEncoder().encode(password);
        manager.createUser(User.withUsername(username).password(encodedPassword).roles("USER").build());
        return manager;
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

Comment: how can I get username and password from the database?

Comment: @SamZiggler you just have to implement your own UserDetailsService, without relying on the InMemoryUserDetailsManager