# Basic Authentication in spring boot using spring-boot-starter-security is not working for latetst version of spring-boot-starter-parent

Tags: java, authentication

I am trying to implement basic auth to my end points of my micro-services. So I used spring-boot-starter-security. But I have noticed that spring-boot-starter-security does not work with spring-boot-starter-parent-version > 2.0.3. So I switched to spring-boot-starter-parent-version > 1.5.2 where it was working perfectly for my reference project.

Can any one help me with any other method for implementing basic auth with latest version of spring-boot-starter-parent?
My problem now is some class where I have written my logic, which is implemented in the latest version, are not functional with the former version of spring boot-starter-parent. Especially where there are methods for reading time stamps.

Here is my pom.xml for reference.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>gs-spring-boot</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.0</version>

    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.16.20</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.13</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.5</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>


    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Hi Thonse. I'd advice to give more details regarding HOW it's failing. Any errors? Things happening? What's a test case? How can people reproduce your trouble?

Answer (score 1):

The way of implementing basic authentication in Spring boot 2 is different as compared to earlier version.Details can be found in below mentioned link.

https://spring.io/blog/2017/09/15/security-changes-in-spring-boot-2-0-m4

For spring boot-2 following approach can be followed. ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50325960/9668336

```
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.provisioning.InMemoryUserDetailsManager;

@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private static final Logger log = LogManager.getLogger();

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // Note:
        // Use this to enable the tomcat basic authentication (tomcat popup rather than spring login page)
        // Note that the CSRf token is disabled for all requests
        log.info("Disabling CSRF, enabling basic authentication...");
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/**").authenticated() // These urls are allowed by any authenticated user
                .and()
                .httpBasic();
        http.csrf().disable();
    }

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        // Get the user credentials from the console (or any other source):
        String username = "hans";
        String password = "hans";

        // Set the inMemoryAuthentication object with the given credentials:
        InMemoryUserDetailsManager manager = new InMemoryUserDetailsManager();
        String encodedPassword = passwordEncoder().encode(password);
        manager.createUser(User.withUsername(username).password(encodedPassword).roles("USER").build());
        return manager;
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

But the problem over here is if any of the end point is accessed via basic auth, other end points can be accesses without any authentication header.